# В wordpress работают ссылки только по умолчанию

Tags: wordpress, плагин

Доброго времени суток.
Проблема заключается в том, что в WP постоянные ссылки работают только при режиме "По умолчанию" и имеют вид "site.com/?p=123", при переключении на любой другой режим выводится пустой белый экран. Кто-то сталкивался с чем-то таким? WP 3.5. 
Плагины:

- akismet
- all-in-one-seo-pack
- better-wp-security
- nextgen-gallery
- wp-no-category-base
- yandex-maps-for-wordpress

Comment: @steelhouse, подобное поведение очень похоже (но не обязательно является) на заглушенный вывод фатальной ошибки: PHP падает, но ему запрещено выводить ошибки, поэтому он не выводит ничего. Если это так, то комментарий @cema93 должен сработать, да и проверить error.log будет весьма хорошей идеей.

Comment: >WP 3.5.

Для начала обновите WP до актуальной версии. Вашу проблему это не решит, но пренебрегать обновлениями WP попросту небезопасно.

По делу. Подозреваю проблемы с mod_rewrite. У вас шаред-хостинг или что-то другое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странно, что именно белый экран, а не сообщение о невозможности найти страницу. Но, скорее всего, вы не настроили на сервере обработку всех адресов вашего блога, движком WP, и сервер пытается обработать переданный путь, как указание к поиску в определённой директории.

Comment: Настройки, как я понимаю, лежат в .htaccess? Там просто ничего нету. А для более гибких настроек в httpd.conf нету доступа.  
Там лежит стандартный код для wp:

    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress

Comment: @steelhouse Код поставлялся вместе с WordPress? Если да, то он должен быть верным. Полагаю, стоит попинать хозяина сервера, чтобы проверил логи, так проблема, скорее всего, именно в неверной адресации. Или добавьте лог в вопрос, если у вас есть доступ.

Answer (score 0):

Я вижу следующее простое решение:

1. Отключаем все плагины.
2. Ставим стандартную тему.
3. Ставим адреса страниц не по умолчанию, а те, которые вы хотите.
4. Проверяете, работает или нет.

Потом делаем всё то же самое, но в обратном порядке.
Так вы сможете выловить, в чем баг.