# Wordpress поддерживает только простые ссылки. Как исправить?

Tags: wordpress, openserver

Имеется сервер на WordPress(v5.2.2), который установлен локально с помощью OpenServer. Сайт работает отлично только тогда, когда все записи имеют простые ссылки: `site.com/?p-123`. Стоит мне поставить любой другой вид ссылок, все страницы (кроме главной), начинают выдавать ошибку: 404 Not Found nginx.

P.S. Нашел такой же вопрос на этом форуме, но ответа на него так и не было

[В wordpress работают ссылки только по умолчанию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/362217/%d0%92-wordpress-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Comment: Такое возникает, когда неправильно настроен nginx. См. настройки в https://wordpress.org/support/article/nginx/

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%9D%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8 А про виндовые форки  пора бы и забыть. Сайт нужно разрабатывать в той среде, в которой он будет жить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё дело в настройке конфигурации nginx. В настройках OpenServer поменяйте сервер на Apache. Проследите, чтобы версия поддерживалась PHP и проверьте в корне сайта наличие файла .htaccess. Если файла нет, создайте со следующим содержимым:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```